# Is it possible that an individual changes its type from one to another class in OWL ontology?

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege

I have a base class of which there are two subclasses. Let say, Base is the base class and A and B are subclasses. Let us have an individual, I, belongs to class A initially. Is it possible in OWL that the same individual starts belonging to class B (and stops belonging to class A) after satisfying the attributes of class B? Note that class A and B are disjoint.

Comment: No, OWL DL reasoning is *monotonic*.